# Best Touchscreen Monitor for Linux under $500

Tags: monitors, touch-screen

Looking for a 17" or larger touchscreen monitor that works with Linux.  It will be used outdoor and I hear capacitive and optical screens are more durable.  It doesn't need to be multi-touch.

I don't see Linux compatibility on the models I've seen, except for the expensive ELOS ones.

Comment: Which model did you choose? I have the task to get a 15 inch model and currently the Elo 1537L is a nice device for indoor usage. Currently I am evaluating whether the Mimo M15680C-OF might be a replacement option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most touchscreens will work with Linux; so long as the hardware doesnt have some vendor specific connector (most fondleslabs I've seen are USB) then you can probably get it to work on *nix although as with most things, there may be some configuration required.

If the vendor says 'compatible with *nix' on the box then that is more of a garuantee that it will work -  but if they don't, it's more likely that they haven't tested or didn't bother putting it on the box rather than the device being inherently incompatible with a *nix system.

You could always ask the retailer in any case, and personally I'd see if I could try it out first because you do get some very cheap but also very very bad ones.

P.S a word to the wise: generally, shopping advice questions are off-topic on stack exchange sites, a better way to ask this would be to say 'How can I tell if a touchscreen monitor would work with Linux' or 'What to look for in a touchscreen for Linux'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I was going to buy one online so it's a bit hard to try it out first or speak with someone who's used the product.  I may just try because supposedly it should just show up as a HID like any mouse, trackpad, or keyboard.

ps: thanks for the etiquette tip.

Comment: no problem :) yep as far as I'm aware it will recognise the device - I have used a very cheap pressure sensetive USB model before, which did not claim linux compatibility, and that's how it showed up on the system. I then installed a few packages to get it to work with X-windows but I can't remember the details, sorry